# Archival of DAM assets along its versions and audit log

Tags: aem

Is there a way to replicate any DAM asset to another **AEM 6.2** instance(author) **maintaining all its versions and its audit log**? The requirement is to archive some of the assets to save some capacity on current instance. Has anyone tried to achieve this earlier? With the below snippet I am able to replicate some of the versions, but this is not consistent and the version being created on other instance is due to DAM Metadata Writeback process on Archival **AEM 6.2** instance:

```
for (Version v : findAllVersions(path, session)) {
            if (v != null) {

                // Set version name to ReplicationOption
                String versionName = v.getName();
                opts.setRevision(versionName);
                // Replicate the version calling replicator service
                replicator.replicate(session,
                        ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE, path, opts);
                session.save();

                logger.info("Replicated for version :" + versionName
                        + " for path :" + path);
            } else {
                logger.info(
                        "Not replicated as no version found for the path.",
                        path);
            }

        }
```

Could anyone please shed some light on this?

Comment: Have you tried using VLT Tool (vlt command) ? We used vlt export command to export all Assets to an external directory as a backup. VLT has Export and RCP options. [ Ref: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/dev-tools/ht-vlttool.html ]